# ¿como hago para sutituir un 0 por paralabra false en slq?

Tags: sql

tengo una tabla Usuarios con el campo UserConect con valor 0, ya tengo la sentencia que saca la informacion de los campos que necesito, pero requiero que en lugar de 0 aparesca la palabra false o true si es otro valor, soy nueva y la verdad no he encontrado un ejemplo de esto. agradezco la ayuda

Answer (score 2):

La solución es muy simple usando un `CASE WHEN` en la consulta. La sintaxis  es la siguiente:

```
SELECT
 CASE WHEN [columna] = 0 THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END [alias]
FROM [nombre de la tabla];
```

Usas el nombre de la columna, y el alias con que quieres que te lance el campo de resultado. Si el campo es cero te devolverá `FALSE` y si es cualquier otra cosa devolverá `TRUE`.

---

### Ejemplo:

Te adjunto un ejemplo en el siguiente [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a43a9/14). Para ello he creado una tabla con tres sencillos campos `id`, `name` y `isStudent`:

```
CREATE TABLE usuario(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL ,
  name VARCHAR(40),
  isStudent INT
);

INSERT INTO Usuario(name, isStudent) VALUES ("Pedro", 1);
INSERT INTO Usuario(name, isStudent) VALUES ("Pablo", 2);
INSERT INTO Usuario(name, isStudent) VALUES ("Arturo", 1);
INSERT INTO Usuario(name, isStudent) VALUES ("Miguel", 0);
```

Para traer el campo numérico `isStudent` como `TRUE` o `FALSE` realizo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  name, 
  CASE WHEN isStudent = 0 THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END isStudent
FROM usuario;
```

Que me devuelve como resultado:

| id | name | isStudent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Pedro | TRUE |
| 2 | Pablo | TRUE |
| 3 | Arturo | TRUE |
| 4 | Miguel | FALSE |

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  IF(UserConect = 0, "FALSE", "TRUE")
FROM
  usuarios;
```

Comment: Solo funciona para `MySql`, en `PostgreSQL` no es válido.